# How to check if either none or all textboxes in an ASP.NET page have text entered?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an invoice application and in the section where the user can enter line items, some of the fields will include: Quantity, Price, Extended Price, Description, etc.

If the user enters something into any of the fields, the corresponding fields are required, but if no data is entered into any field, then nothing is required in the corresponding fields.  What is an efficient and clean way of doing this without doing a bunch of if statements?

I guess this is like doing validation if only one textbox has text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this in the ServerValidate event of a CustomValidator.

```
// test for all textboxes having some text in them...
e.IsValid = (from TextBox c in this.Controls
             where c is TextBox
             select c).All(tb => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text));
```

That might need some tinkering to get right - but you get the idea.  Change accordingly to test for all textboxes being blank.

You could also use jQuery for the client side validation in your CustomValidator

```
function clientValidate(sender, e) {

    // get array of textboxes with a common css class
    var textBoxes = $("#SomeCssSelector input").val();

    // loop here to test for having text or no text.
    e.IsValid = ... ;


}
```

Comment: Is this going to touch every control on the page to see if it is a textbox?  Faster to program but perhaps not faster to process?

Comment: yeah, it probably will walk the controls collection.  Its a standard Linq to Objects query - so I imagine that they've optimized that code where possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a TextBox array and store references to all related text boxes in the array.  When ever you need to you could then iterate over the array in a for loop looking for the first item with a value.  As soon as you find one with a value you know all the other items in that array also need values.

Additionally, if you have other groups of related text boxes you could create additional arrays to help keep them grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways if this is ASP.NET.

1. Use field validators that are available in ASP.NET.
2. Use JavaScript for Windows Forms.

For Windows Forms, also use control validators, or you could use a simple function where you pass a control array. If any item in the array is filled then it requires all items to be filled by returning which fields are not filled, etc.